# JQuery mouseenter handler possible to ignore an element

Tags: jquery, css-position, mouseenter

I have a situation whereby a series of overlapping divs carry a shadow effect. Using position:absolute, they have a shadow effect that rests over the last div.

The problem is that each div has a mouse enter function assigned to it. So the user can have the mouse hovering over one, but because it is touching the shadow of another, the other has its function triggered.

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the shadow as a trigger for the mouse enter function altogether and just use the div itself.

```
<div class="hoop"><div class="shadow"></div></div>
<div class="hoop"><div class="shadow"></div></div>
<div class="hoop"><div class="shadow"></div></div>
<div class="hoop"><div class="shadow"></div></div>
<div class="hoop"><div class="shadow"></div></div>

.hoop {
   float:left;
   width:200px;
   height:400px; position:relative
}
.shaddow {
   position:absolute; left:-70px;
}
```

Try that

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code?

Comment: Right I've done it with CSS3 box shaddow but if anyone knows a way of doing it that will be compatible with old browsers do let me know

Answer (score 0):

If they are positioned absolutely and one is on top of the other the mouseenter handler with only go off for the top element (the one with the highest z-index) unless the divs are inside of each other.

Comment: I know that. That is the problem. Do you know how to change it so that that does not happen